# File list to text file in a-z order and a new row for each result

Tags: linux, sorting

I would like to to find every .URL-file in a directory and post it to a textfile. I want the textfile to be sorted in alphabetical order and every result in each row

```
find /files/ -type f -name "*.url"  > urllist.txt
```

This just post the files to a textfile without sorting and without row breaks. 
Are there any better command or any other flag I can use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's wrong with `find /files/ -type f -name "*.url" | sort > urllist.txt`?

Comment: The sorting works. But it doesn't make a new row for me. Everything is printed in a single line. Like:  files/directory1/a_file.urlfiles/directory2/b_file.url

Comment: Then change find to `find /files -type f -name "*.url" -printf "%h/%f\n" | sort > urllist.txt`  (add `%h` to capture the directory information)

Comment: Since the default `-print` will print one name per line, unless there is something funky going on with line-ends, etc... "What OS are you on?" Are you executing it in some environment other than Unix/Linux?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem with the lack of row breaking seems to persist. I'm running Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Are you piping it in some odd way? I have a Raspberry Pi3 open in one of my terminal windows and it behaves exactly the way any normal Linux box would. How are you getting to the Raspberry? I ssh with an xterm. If you are using a windoze terminal, you may very well have control code or character set issues. If you are on windoze, then look at PuTTY as a terminal. It can be set to mimic an xterm.

Comment: I'm using ssh through Putty on a Windows machine. I'm certain the code you guys have provided is correct and that there is something goofy with my setup. I will look into it. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Yes, there are quite a number of options for PuTTY. The two primary ones I set are to make sure the character encoding is UTF-8, and make sure you have the 'middle-mouse pastes' (it extends selection by default). Other than that, I like the ... I believe it's Lucida Typewriter font. That will give you a very usable terminal. Do *not* forget to save the settings with your host profile. (if you just change the settings, but don't save them with your hostname, you have to do it all over again for the next connection.

Comment: It's `Window -> Translation -> Remote Character Set -> UTF-8` and then `Window -> Selection -> xterm (Right extends, Middle pastes)`. I actually have `DejaVu Sans Mono 8` as the font.

Comment: From Win7 using PuTTY into my Raspberry Pi3 box, I have no problem at all with the output of the `find` command being on separate lines (just by default)

Comment: Sounds to me like the `find` command is outputting LF line endings and whatever Windows utility you're reading the file with wants CRLF line endings.

Answer (score 0):

```
find /files/ -type f -name "*.url" | cut -c 8- | sort > urllist.txt
```

This one-liner should do the job. cut removes "/files/" from every entry & then sort sorts the result.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It solved the sorting issue. But they aren't breaking row though. Every result is still placed in a single row.

Comment: Could you show the result you are expecting? I thought by row break you mean results being placed in a single row.

Comment: I apologize for not being distinct. 

I was hoping for this:

files/directory1/a_file.url
files/directory2/b_file.url

They are now presented as:

files/directory1/a_file.urlfiles/directory2/b_file.url

Comment: Exuse me again. The cut works. But it's no need for it. I modified the results above my self.

Comment: It actually breaks the file too & gives the output you are expecting & you are right, cut is not necessary if having "/files/" is not a big deal. New lines are different in Linux & Windows so this might be reason: https://superuser.com/questions/374028/how-are-n-and-r-handled-differently-on-linux-and-windows